# ZStack - IOS 14 beta - Zstack fly on the keyboard

Tags: swiftui, ios14, zstack

In new IOS 14 beta i use ZStack to display badge on my tabs. When keyboard is appear - [zstack fly on the keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4byOZ.png), but it must be fixed in the bottom. IOS 13 - has nothing like this.

```
ZStack {
            Circle()
              .foregroundColor(.red)
            Text("\(self.realm.ItemsAll.count)")
              .foregroundColor(.white)
              .font(Font.system(size: 11))
             
             
}.frame(width: 15, height: 15)
```

Comment: Needed code to reproduce. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)